# Spring MVC - HTTP GET requests for static resources are handled by custom servlet

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, servlets, resources, static

I'm working on a proxy servlet that maps all requests.
I specified web.xml in the following way:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Servlet to proxy all requests.</description>
    <display-name>ProxyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.epam.alpha.servlets.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This way all the requests are handled by my proxy servlet, except /home and /admin/* that are reserved for the home page and the admin pages. This works nice!

Now, I would like to use javascript and css files in my jsp pages. They are placed under resources folder, so those are at the right place.

In servlet-context.xml the following is given:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The problem is that my servlet catches all the GET requests to static resources. The resources are found, and used, if I comment out the servlet mapping for ProxyServlet, of course the proxy servlet does not work in this case. On the other hand, if I don't reference the javascript file from jsp, the proxy servlet works (no request for static resource will happen). Help!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What would you like to do with the proxy servlet? What does it actually do?

Comment: There are aliases that will be mapped to urls, the goal is to access these pages as it would run on localhost. Example:
- alias 'google' is mapped to http://www.google.com.
When I type http://localhost:8080/ProxyServlet/google, will see google.com. That is the goal. The proxy servlet processes the above request and reads the response and shows the result in the browser. Practically all requests should be handled by this proxy servlet (that we created), except for some reserved aliases, like home, or admin, that will be used for maintenance purposes.

Comment: If your js and css files should be served by Spring's resources mechanism, the /resources path should be mapped to the Spring dispatcher servlet, shouldn't it? So, adding a mapping for /resources/* to the appServlet should fix everything.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried. It seems to work, at least there is no errors on the console and the page loads. However, the javascript is not working, like the file is not found. I think the mapping in the servlet-context.xml should do the mapping, so I'm not sure it's needed to add it to web.xml too. Anywat, I tried, and it's not working. :(

Comment: Okay, now I got `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ProxyServlet/resources/scripts/js/validatorScripts.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'` on the console...

Comment: Please show the contents of the HTML page containing the link to the JavaScript file. Why is the URL beginning with /ProxyServlet/?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! :)
I have this in my **admin.jsp**:
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="resources/scripts/js/validatorScripts.js"></script>`. This is in the **servlet-context.xml**: `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`. This is the url I type: `http://localhost:8080/ProxyServlet/admin` (ProxyServlet is the name of the app). This is on the console: `... No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ProxyServlet/resources/scripts/js/validatorScripts.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to serve a page through a Spring controller and have a JS script loaded by this page using a similar configuration :

- A dispatcher servlet
- a servlet mapped to / (the proxy servlet)

I've had to

- map the path /resources/* to the dispatcher servlet in web.xml (in addition to the other mappings)
- use the following spring context file:

servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.free.jnizet.springtest"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans>
```

The key point is the `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` element. Without this element, Spring doesn't find any mapping for the JS file in /resources/.

Comment: It's working!! I still don't understand the whole story, why Spring found js mappings when my proxy servlet was out from the picture, but anyway. The bottom is that this solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: I think Spring didn't found it. The default servlet found it, because the path of the JS is its actual path. You only need the spring resource mapping to defeat the proxy servlet "mapped to everything" mapping.